# SQL Server delete records that are spaces, zeros, and blanks

Tags: sql-server

I have a column where the length must be 6 digits. The problem I am trying to figure out is this:
if the column contains any blanks or 0s or just a space then I need to exclude that record from the query result:

```
Column A
964015
00279R
0


25015
0
352
8290
0
```

The result needs to be:

```
Column A
964015
00279R
C25015
C00352
C08290
```

I coded the part where it is less than 6 digits but the part where I exclude the 0's, spaces, and blanks is where I am stuck. Any hints are appreciated. Here is the portion of my code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Hello( [Column A] varchar(6))
INSERT INTO #Hello VALUES('00279R')
INSERT INTO #Hello VALUES('35269')
INSERT INTO #Hello VALUES('0')
INSERT INTO #Hello VALUES(' ')
INSERT INTO #Hello VALUES('')
INSERT INTO #Hello VALUES('352')
INSERT INTO #Hello VALUES('8290')


SELECT (Case When Len([Column A]) = 5 THEN 'C' + [Column A] 
        WHEN Len([Column A]) = 4 THEN 'C' + '0' + [Column A] 
        WHEN Len([Column A]) = 3 THEN 'C' + '00' + [Column A] 
        WHEN Len([Column A]) = 2 THEN 'C' + '000' + [Column A] 
        WHEN Len([Column A]) = 1 THEN 'C' + '0000' + [Column A] 
        WHEN Len([Column A]) = 0 THEN 'C' + '00000' + [Column A] 
        ELSE [Column A] END)
        FROM #Hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN([Column A]) = 6 THEN [Column A]
    ELSE STUFF('C000000', 7 - LEN([Column A]), 6, [Column A])
    END
FROM Hello
WHERE RIGHT('000000' + ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM([Column A])), ''), 6) <> '000000'
```

This will exclude the empty rows, as well as those that are just `000000`. Further, whatever is left will end up getting padded to the left with zeros and only be 6-characters long.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle to prove it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0df93/1).

Comment: What kind of SQL Server magic is that? Thank you so much. Works perfectly. much appreciated.

Comment: @user3221917: I'm glad I could be of assistance, and here is the [MSDN documentation on STUFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx).